# creating case types with different component than CiviCase for attached activity types

Tags: civicase, developer, hooks

We created an extension for tasks management which define a new civicrm component called CiviTask  .. I want to create 4 case types (with attached activity Types set and a standard timeline ) when installing the extension but I want the attached activity types set have to be attached to CiviTask component instead of CiviCase component  .. I tried to used hook_civicrm_caseTypes  and then hook_civicrm_managed  hook with no luck since civicrm is hardcoded to create the attached activity types for CiviCase component (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/e70cec100c435fe48e472f272f409d3887dcf8dc/CRM/Case/ManagedEntities.php#L84) .. I tried to change the component ID field in extenstion postInstall function but hook_civicrm_caseTypes and hook_civicrm_managed hooks run after postInstall function so I cannot change anything there ...  then I decided to drop hook_civicrm_caseTypes/hook_civicrm_managed hooks approach and doing stuff old school by creating these case types manually on extension life cycle ( install/disable/enable/uninstall ) so for extension install function I call this function  **hrcase_createDefaultCaseTypes();** , and here is the function implementation :

```
function hrcase_createDefaultCaseTypes()  {
  hrcase_updateSystemActivityTypes('CiviTask');
  $caseTypes = include __DIR__ . '/CRM/HRCase/DefaultCaseTypes.php';
  foreach ($caseTypes as $case)  {
  $params = ['name' => $case['name']];
  $defaults = NULL;
  $caseType = CRM_Case_BAO_CaseType::retrieve($params, $defaults);
  if ($caseType == NULL)  {
    $caseParams = $case['params'];
    CRM_Case_BAO_CaseType::create($caseParams);
    hrcase_createDefaultActivityTypes($case['params']['definition']  ['activityTypes'], 'CiviTask');
  }
}
$specialActivityTypes =
  [
    ['name' => 'Revoke access to databases'],
    ['name' => 'Block work email ID']
  ];
hrcase_createDefaultActivityTypes($specialActivityTypes, 'CiviCase');}
```

here is the links for the rest of  functions and files to help understanding this  :

https://github.com/civicrm/civihr/blob/PCHR-459-2nd-test/hrcase/CRM/HRCase/DefaultCaseTypes.php

https://github.com/civicrm/civihr/blob/PCHR-459-2nd-test/hrcase/hrcase.php#L565

https://github.com/civicrm/civihr/blob/PCHR-459-2nd-test/hrcase/hrcase.php#L780

but even when creating case types and activities like this , civicrm will still create the activity types in the list so I end up with duplicate activity types one with component ID  = CiviCase and a similar one with Component ID = CiviTask

Here is a screenshots :

[image]

[image]

So why CiviCRM still create these acitivty types since I don't use managed entities here , how can I avoid that ?

Comment: Since your new component is so similar to CiviCase, have you considered just instead customizing CiviCase?

Comment: I didn't really witnessed the creation of this extension/component from the beginning so probably there is some business decision  behind that  .. so I am trying to live with the current situation but maybe later we will consider that , but thanks for the note.

Comment: Maybe try a debugger to see when they getting created? I don't see anything obvious in those codes.